# What is the best way to shorten simple if statements?

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to shorten simple if statements?

For example:

```
if(sum > max){
  max = sum;
}
```

I am using this line which works fine.

```
sum > max ? max = sum : 0;
```

Oddly the line below gave me an error:

```
sum > max || max = sum;
```

> ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

`>` has greater precedence than `||` so because JavaScript is short circuiting I would have expected it to evaluate the right side operand only if the left side operand is true.

Comment: I'd use `max = Math.max(max, sum)`

Comment: If I was reviewing code, I'd honestly rather see the first form. If your logic takes more than a glance to comprehend when it shouldn't, that's bad for maintainability.

Comment: I am more curious as to why the || does not work as expected.  The error states that the left side operand is not valid.

Comment: || does works as expected, but it does not expect a variable assignment

Comment: The issue with your last one is, that `=` has incredibly low precedence, in other words, it's `((sum > max) || max) = sum`.

Comment: @j.a. sorry, the title "What is the best way to shorten simple if statements?" is misleading, in that case. The answer is "don't shorten what's already simple"

Comment: @j.a. doesn't work because assignment has lower precedence than either `>` or `||`. So you're assigning to the result of `||` - `(sum > max || max) = sum`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ternary

```js
max = sum > max ? sum : max
```

**Edit**:

But for this specific case, I would prefer as @Iłya Bursov mentionned

```js
max = Math.max(max, sum)
```

Comment: @j.a. It wasn't my downvote, but you mention in the comments "_I am more curious as to why the || does not work as expected_". This doesn't mention that part at all.

Comment: @j.a. I disagree this is the best way to shorten simple `if` statements. Even more so for this particular `if` statement.

Comment: @VLAZ what do you mean ?

Comment: @MickaelB. I do not like the conditional operator. It makes it harder to read. I have to literally read that line twice (at least) to understand what is happening. Since it's assigning to `max` I'd expect it to return the higher of the two numbers but I can't tell that at a glance. Even if it's correct *now*, it is easy for somebody making a "trivial" change to completely change the logic by accident *because* it's easy to misinterpret. `max = Math.max(sum, max)` immediately tells me that what the logic is, that it's correct, and will not be easily broken in the future.

Comment: `Math.max` is already answered in first comment that's why I didn't put it there. And yes it' the best way for this specific problem so I'll edit to add it. But for general conditional assignments I find this one way more readable and commonly used than some wrapped assignments in parenthesis with pipes.

Answer (score 1):

For the last one

```
sum > max || max = sum;
```

you have an [invalid assignment left-hand side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Invalid_assignment_left-hand_side), because logical OR has a higher precedence than assignment.

To get it working, you nee to wrap the assignment in parentheses.

```
sum > max || (max = sum);
```

Comment: `sum > max || max = sum;` is essentially evaluated as `( (sum > max) || max ) = sum` so, if `sum = 1` and `max = 3`, then `( (1 > 3) || 3 ) = 3` -> `( true || 3 ) = 3` -> `3 = 3`